# how to use plot() when value to be plotted is in the local block of if() in pinescript tradingview

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am a beginner in coding world and i am learning pine script.

I am having trouble plotting a variable which in the if() function and not in the global scope of the script.

I am getting this compiling error

**line 73: Undeclared identifier 'tbf'**

how do I plot **"tbf"**?

i have blockquoted the tbf variable line near the end

here is the script

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
// getting user inputs -----{

//Input Volume ("D" from Levine’s formula)
Vol_D     = input.int(title = "Vol_D", defval = 1, tooltip = "input Vol_D that is total volume")
//Bar Price to use; suggest "Low" for TopFinder and "High" for BottomFinder
TBF_Price = input.source(title = "Price type", defval = low)
//Bar Volume information to use; suggest "volume", or "1" if no volume information
MyVolume  = na(volume) ? 1 : volume
//StartBar is where the topfinder or bottomefinder will start from
StartBar  = input.int(title = 'Start Bar', minval = 1, maxval = 100000, defval = 10000)

//}----- end of user inputs

// setting up a start point -----{

start = bar_index == StartBar - 1 
    
//}----- end of setting up a start point

// assiging variables for calcualtion  -----{

//add current bar’s price * volume to cumulative total
pv = 0.0
pv := pv + TBF_Price * MyVolume
//running total of volume begin calculation of TBF price
vol = 0.0
vol := vol + MyVolume
//}------ end assiging variables for calcualtion

// calcualtion begins -----{

//begin calculation of tfbf
if (Vol_D  != 0)
    //store copy of input volume
    _D = Vol_D 
    //calculate "e" per Levine’s formula 
    e = vol * (1 - vol / _D) 
    //if "e" greater than zero, continue to calculate TBF price otherwise, TBF is completed 
    if (e > 0)
        //temporary copy of "e"
        eT = e
        //used for iteration iterate backwards until the cumulative displaced volume is greater than or equal to "e"
        j = -1
            
        while (eT > 0)
            j = j + 1
            eT = eT - MyVolume[j]
            
            
        //If displaced volume is greater than "e" (nearly always), an interpolated pv amount is calculated for "j" bars ago using only that part of
        //"j" bar’s volume needed to make cumulative displaced volume equal to "e". Note that at this point, "eT" is negative and contains the partial volume
        //of "j" bars ago that should be excluded.
        if (eT < 0) 
            pvInt = TBF_Price[j] * (MyVolume[j] + eT) 
        else 
            pvInt = 0
            
            //calculate TBF curve price for this bar
           

>           tbf = (pv - pv[j] + pvInt) / e

            //calculate percent TBF completion
            pct_D = vol / _D * 100
            
     
//}------ end of calculation

// plotting tbf line -----{

//plotting tbf
plot(tbf == 0 ? na : tbf, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2)

//}----- end of plotting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says "tbf" is not declared, which is true based on the code
Where can I see it?

Comment: it is above three lines from end of calculation in the end
```
tbf = (pv - pv[j] + pvInt) / e
```

Comment: got it
tbf is declared in the if statement and then not available outside of that if statement
Declare it with the var keyword outside the if statement and inside the if statement do

tbf := (pv - pv[j] + pvInt) / e

using the := instead of = operator